# Struct not being stored in mapping when it contains more than two 'string' properties. Bug?

Tags: solidity, storage, string, mapping, struct

I am playing around with Solidity, and have encountered an extremely bemusing issue. I want to have a mapping of Address instances (postal addresses **NOT** the address type)

Address is a custom defined struct as follows:

```
//Struct representing a postal address
struct Address {

    bool initialized;

    string identifier;

    string street;
    string city;
}
```

Now, I have a public function for building an address, defined as follows:

```
function buildAddress(string identifier, string street, string city) public returns(string){

    Address storage addressInstance = addresses[sha3(identifier)];

    addressInstance.initialized = true;
    addressInstance.identifier = identifier;
    addressInstance.street = street;
    addressInstance.city = city;

    return identifier;
}
```

and I have a getter defined as follows:

```
function getAddressStreet(string addressIdentifier) public constant returns(string) {

    Address storage addressInstance = addresses[sha3(addressIdentifier)];

    if (addressInstance.initialized == false) {
        // Unknown node, just return 0x0;
        return "No address";
    }

    return addressInstance.street;   
}
```

My issue is that this **does not** work. 'Building' an address, mining the transaction, and then 'getting' the street name returns 'No address'.

What is bemusing however is that if I remove one string property from the address struct e.g city, it all works perfectly.. as expected.

That is to say that when there are **more than 2** string properties in the struct, the Address is seemingly not persisted on the block chain.

I suspect this may be something to do with storage locations, but having read the appropriate documentation a number of times I cannot see anything that is obviously incorrect..

Could anyone provide any insight into this? This may well be a bug, but I imagine that it is more likely a simple oversight on my part. Any clarification would be appreciated !

Thomas

Comment: I had a very similar problem a few months ago with a string in a struct with other variables (ints in my case). It did turn out to be a bug. Here is the issue on the <a href="http://forum.ethereum.org/discussion/3475/odd-behavior-with-strings-in-structs">forum</a> and <a href="https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/issues/74">a link to the github issue</a> which was closed. I'd say open up an issue, definitely looks like a similar bug with storage locations.

Comment: @RobertMcCone for future reference, links are formated as `[text](link)` in comments.

Comment: Could you please provide the full code for a simple contract that behaves like that? Especially the mapping you use is of interest.

Comment: Chris, I have updated the [Github issue](https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/issues/381) with a link to a [gist](https://gist.github.com/clowestab/ca86d0ee43de1e918c22) which demonstrates the issue.

The Github issue lists steps to reproduce.

Comment: According to the comments on the question, this is likely a bug within solidity. https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/issues/381

Comment: @PiperMerriam I converted your answer to a comment, with the hope of attracting an actual answer, since even the Github issue has been closed without resolution.

Answer (score 2):

According to the comments on the question, this is likely a bug within solidity.

https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/issues/381